# Is there any way to use pvals as an numpy array in numpy.random.multinomial?

Tags: python

I try to generate the data that follow multinomial distribution by using numpy.random.multinomial but because of my probability values is an numpy array. I keep getting a message says "Object too deep for desired array"

Here is my code:

```
x1=np.random.normal(loc=0,scale=0.5,size=100)
beta1=2
beta2=0.5
d=1+np.exp(beta1*x1)+np.exp(beta2*x1)
p1=1/d
p2=np.exp(beta1*x1)/d
p3=np.exp(beta2*x1)/d
```

```
y=np.random.multinomial(1,np.stack((p1,p2,p3),axis=1),100)
```

Comment: Are you trying to have different probabilities for each of the samples you're drawing from the multinomial distribution?

Comment: yeah, I want to get three outputs from different probabilities.

Comment: it should work on newer versions, please check this related issue check [`numpy.random.multinomial` generating incorrect outputs for large n #16587](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/16587) (closed)

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/glmfit.html

Comment: I sincerely appreciate your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to some issues in the application of log to random floating point numbers, the stream may change when sampling from multinomial or another functions if 0 is generated in the underlying [MT19937](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/bit_generators/mt19937.html#numpy.random.MT19937) random stream. There is a 10^53 in chance of this occurring. If a 0 is encountered in the underlying generator, then the incorrect value produced (either `numpy.inf` or `numpy.nan`) is now dropped.

> *recent versions of numpy use a instance `random.Generator` to invoke `multinomial` method*

```py
import numpy as np
x1=np.random.normal(loc=0,scale=0.5,size=100)
beta1=2
beta2=0.5
d=1+np.exp(beta1*x1)+np.exp(beta2*x1)
p1=1/d
p2=np.exp(beta1*x1)/d
p3=np.exp(beta2*x1)/d
y = np.random.default_rng()
y.multinomial(1, np.stack((p1,p2,p3),axis=1), size=100)
```

output:

```
array([[0, 0, 1],
       ...
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0]], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, can I ask another question? If I would like to give the same probability for each sample, which formula can I use?

Comment: After I try your code I still get an error: ValueError Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_270164/2614251069.py in <module>
----> 1 y.multinomial(1,p,size=100)

_generator.pyx in numpy.random._generator.Generator.multinomial()

ValueError: object too deep for desired array

Comment: Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: I certainly do not know why you still getting errors, however i am using `np.__version__=='1.23.5'`, also i found some references to probabilistic multiplicative multinomial and this points to me to an **R** functions like `glm` this is used to calculate fit generalized models, and all what i recommend is to use `numpy.polyfit(x, y, deg, rcond=None, full=False, w=None, cov=False)`.

Comment: Thanks again, it is working when I upgrade the numpy version.